# How i can Save Mediaplayer state by SharePreference?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-mediaplayer, media-player

When I switch between activities how can I save the status of Mediaplayer in this code

```
    on = findViewById(R.id.on);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.simba);
    mp.start();

    on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.pause();
                on.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);

            } else {
                mp.start();
                on.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: did you try using Share Preference to store it? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: No,  how can I use it in this code ?